# Cropping colors out of a JPEG image with MS Office Picture Manager

Tags: image, ms-office, jpeg, transparency, crop

I am instructed to "crop out the white background" of a JPEG image in MS Office Picture Manager. The image is a multicolored shape on a white background, with no white anywhere else in the picture, so there is no danger of cropping out anything but the background if I somehow remove all the white color. But I confess to being utterly clueless, having never done it. How do I crop out just the background? If I simply resize the (rectangular) crop area, some white will remain. The question is, how do I crop out just the background?

I have no Photoshop installed on my machine. I guess making the background transparent would also work, but I don't know how to do that, either. Searching for "background" under MS Office Help turns up nothing but instructions on how to make the picture my background image, and I can't find much that is helpful on the Web either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the confusion was due to the fact that only MS Office 2010 or newer can crop out backgrounds, and installed on my machine is still MS Office 2007. Once I got my hands on a newer version of Office, I could, in theory, have cropped the background out even in Word or Excel, as described, for example, here:

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Remove-the-background-of-a-picture-c0819a62-6844-4190-8d67-6fb1713a12bf

However, my image was a JPEG file, and it turns out that JPEG images can't really have transparent backgrounds. After the white background was cropped out, the image file did become smaller, but, as far as appearance is concerned, the white background seemed to simply have been replaced with a black one. In the end, after learning that .gif or .png formats are preferable if one wants a transparent background, and that conversion to .gif often entails deterioration in image quality, I saved the image in .png format and cropped its background out as described under the link above, successfully this time.